# Alter table issue with the SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like run the below alter table command post my Spark batch job completes, so to concatenate all smaller files available in blob location to one bigger file every day. Table output format is ORC. Is there a way i can achieve this using SparkSQL. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE TABLENAME CONCATENATE")
```

[image]

Comment: spark version ?

Comment: Spark version 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

As per spark source code, `ALTER TABLE <> CONCATENATE` option is not implemented or not supported as of now. Please check below code for more information.

[Spark SQL Parser](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkSqlParser.scala)

[Spark Un Supported Hive Native Commands](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/73dd6cf9b558f9d752e1f3c13584344257ad7863/sql/catalyst/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBase.g4#L217)